# PHP isset equal $var1 or $var2

Tags: php, url-routing

I'm trying to make routing system.

**What I want to do:**

Url: `http://localhost/wiki.php?post_id=1` invoke second if

Url's: `http://localhost/wiki.php?post_id=1&action=upvote`
`http://localhost/wiki.php?post_id=1&action=downvote` invoke first if

This is routing system:

```
if(isset($_GET['post_id']) & ((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "upvote" || "downvote")){
    //Do stuff
}else if(isset($_GET['post_id'])){
    //Do stuff
}
```

**Problem:**

Url's: `http://localhost/wiki.php?post_id=1&action=upvote` `http://localhost/wiki.php?post_id=1&action=downvote` work like they are supposed to.

But url: `http://localhost/wiki.php?post_id=1` invokes first not second if too...

> Notice: Undefined index: action in D:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\WikiController.php on line 18

Line 18: `$rate = $_GET['action'];` it's inside in first if.

While testing I figured out that if I change `if(isset($_GET['post_id']) & ((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "upvote" || "downvote")){`

too

```
 if(isset($_GET['post_id']) & ((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "upvote")){
```

or

```
 if(isset($_GET['post_id']) & ((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "downvote")){
```

It works fine. But I want to learn how to do this right, not just simply made 2 different routers.

Comment: You have a single & where && should be. Additionally, your or condition is just checking the string `downvote` which will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this part `(exp) == "upvote" || "downvote"` does not work like you suppose it does. It only tests if `exp` is equal to `"upvote"`, the second part `"downvote"` is understood as a boolean which is `true`, so you stay in the first part of the alternative..

try with

```
if(isset($_GET['post_id']) && (($exp = (isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null)) == "upvote" || $exp == "downvote")){
```

Comment: @ArtisUļjanovs The conditional check wouldn't affect your redirect, I would ensure that your paths are still correct after using this.

Comment: @Absorbing Sorry, deleted my comment. Didn't saw. Somehow my server had turned down that's why I had this error

Answer (score 1):

For clarification, a single (ampersand) `&` is "bitwise":

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Therefore, you need to change your `&` to `&&`.

From the manual:

> $a & $b    And Bits that are set in both $a and $b are set.

What you're after is the logical `&&` operator:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

> $a && $b   And TRUE if both $a and $b are TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

`|| "downvote"` will always return true since you're not comparing it to anything. You have to add `(isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) ==` in front of that string too.

So your statement would be:

```
if(isset($_GET['post_id']) && ((isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "upvote" || (isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null) == "downvote")){
    //Do stuff
}else if(isset($_GET['post_id'])){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$routes = [
    'upvote','downvote'
    ];
    if(isset($_GET['post_id']) && isset($_GET['action']) && in_array($_GET['action'],$routes)){
       echo 'running if';
    }else if(isset($_GET['post_id'])){
      echo 'running else if';
    }
```

You are missing && was the problem, i just change this for dynamic route if you need to change in future!